# Как у VideoView узнать длину ролика

Tags: android, videoview

Как у `VideoView` узнать длину ролика , и проецировать её на полосу или `seekbar`.

Comment: Вопрос к Android Studio Не имеет отношения, т. к. приложение будет работать на Android-устройстве, а не в Android Studio. Android Studio - Это всего лишь среда разработки

Answer (score 3):

```
VideoView.getDuration()
```

Вернет вам длинну загруженного ролика в милисекундах. Вызывать можно после события `onPrepared();`